# How to call the codeigniter controller funcation in model?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am fairly new to Codeigniter and am trying to call in a function from my model but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be bad design that doesn't follow MVC pattern. Model should contain only DB related methods wjich shouldn't be in controller at all. Post some code to clarify your request hete.